# Posix Thread Synchronization Primitives: pthread_cond_signal() and pthread_cond_wait()

Tags: multithreading, pthreads

I was writing a multithreading code using pthread_cond in conjuction with mutexes, which made me wonder:

1. is the signal one time, so if the signal is sent before the other thread is waiting for it, the other thread will keep waiting indefinitely?
2. Since cond_wait() unlocks the mutex, is it a thumb rule to write this statement JUST before mutex_unlock(), (I realise this makes the latter redundant, but I do that just for clarity) or are there many scenarios where you would want to write the function outside the mutex lock?

Comment: Maybe you should put `pthread_cond_signal` and `pthread_cond_wait` in your title, to avoid confusion with the standard C / POSIX functions `signal` and `wait`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make this your mantra:

> Only ever wait **for** something ...

Waiting should almost always look like this:

```
if (pthread_mutex_lock(...) != 0) {
    /* something terrible happened, panic */
}

while (test-condition) {
    pthread_cond_wait(...)
}

pthread_mutex_unlock(...)
```

If the exclusive check of `test-condition` fails, and so a context enters `pthread_cond_wait` the associated mutex will be atomically unlocked.

This means another context can enter code that looks like:

```
if (pthread_mutex_lock(...) != 0) {
    /* panic */
}

test-condition = false;

pthread_cond_signal(...);

pthread_mutex_unlock(...);
```

Changing the predicate and atomically waking the first context that is in the call to `pthread_cond_wait`, which in turn checks the predicate `test-condition` and can jump past the loop.

If we just look at the waiting code again:

```
if (pthread_mutex_lock(...) != 0) {
    /* something terrible happened, panic */
}

while (test-condition) {
    pthread_cond_wait(...)
}

pthread_mutex_unlock(...)
```

Between the call to wait and unlock, there is always exclusivity; Either because the mutex was acquired exclusively (the predicated wait loop was not entered), or because before returning from a call to`pthread_cond_wait` the mutex was re-acquired atomically.

Synchronization is hard to get right, and is costly for a multi-threaded application; One should attempt to keep critical sections simple to squeeze the margins for error to their minimum size.

Another important thing to do is check the return values of all these `pthread_*` calls; The return value is important information about state that you always need to know, and nearly always need to act upon.

Some useful man pages (for return values):

- [pthread_mutex_lock](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_lock)
- [pthread_cond_wait](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_wait)
- [pthread_cond_signal](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_signal)

Comment: If you're paranoid enough to check `pthread_mutex_lock()`s return value, why not `pthread_mutex_unlock()`s as well?

Comment: It's not real code ... proper error checking should be performed :)

Comment: I see the principle behind such use of wait(), but this involves only paranoid situations. What if I want to use it for normal scenarios? Like http://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/quiz_multithreading.php this code?